# In Highcharts after zoom in and zoom out some of the x-axis values are not display

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, linechart

In Highcharts line chart some of the x-axis labels are not display after zoom in and zoom out.

```
Please have a look from following link ==>> https://jsfiddle.net/2yc9ozwk/
```

To reproducing this issue you need to adjust output window width minimum for more clarity check below snaps

**1) Initially when chart load, It will show all x-axis labels.**

[image]

**2) After chart zoom in click on 'reset zoom' button**

[image]

3) After zoom out some labels are not displaying.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks like a bug, so I reported it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10532

To workaround, use `tickPositioner` function:

```
xAxis: {
    tickPositioner: function() {
        var ticks = [];

        for (var i = this.dataMin; i < this.dataMax; i++) {
            ticks.push(i);
        }

        return ticks;
    },
    ...
},
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7bgj6tvs/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner